# I keep gettin an stoi conversion error when trying to open a file

Tags: c++

So im trying to read a file's contents but everything I run the program I get an error stating

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion

I cant seem to figure out why it's giving me that error. When I input the file name and hit enter I get this error.

```
void displayGrades(string fileInput, vector<GradeItem> &content) {
  ifstream myFile(fileInput);
  string date, description, type, tempG, tempMG, line;
  int grade, maxGrade;

  std::getline(myFile, line);
  while(std::getline(myFile, line)){
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::getline(iss, date);
    std::getline(iss, description);
    std::getline(iss, type);
    std::getline(iss, tempG);

    grade = stoi(tempG);

    std::getline(iss, tempMG);
    maxGrade = stoi(tempMG);

    GradeItem G(date, description, type, grade, maxGrade);
    content.push_back(G);
  }
}
```

File contents:

> Date, Description, Type, Grade, MaxGrade
> 04/13/2022,Today is a good day,quiz,100,1

Any help would be nice!

Comment: I dont think getline does what you think it does, by default it will grab one whole line until it hits `\n`. You seem to be expecting it to stop at the comma. You have to specify the terminator `std::getline(iss, date, ',');`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look over our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'd like to run your code and see what it's doing, but I can't do that without writing a lot of the code you've left out.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or just writing out `tempG` to see what it contains?

Comment: Thanks for that, the thing is when I put the extra argument into the function `std::getline(iss, date, ' , ');`  it gives me an error stating that no overloaded instance of operator matches the argument list. I should have all the necessary libraries included..

Comment: i dont know what to tell you other than it works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99da5b03622efe4c and theres a sample [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that does something similar.

Comment: *"I cant seem to figure out why it's giving me that error."* -- OK, I'll give you a hint. When the error message says that the problems stems from a call to `stoi`, then the (immediate) error stems from the line where you call `stoi`. That might not be your true error, but it is a starting point. Trim down your *example* code as close as you can to that line while retaining the error. I'd expect something like `int main() { std::string tempG = /* fill in what you've confirmed this variable holds */; int grade = stoi(tempMG); }` as a [mre] for this sort of error. Welcome to debugging!

Comment: `' , '` is not a character as `getline` expects it. It's a multibyte literal and those are just weird.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

[std::getline](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getline-string-c/) when not provided by a delimiter reads the whole line of the input stream.

So, what's happening here is that you are reading the whole line in the file into the date variable, while the other strings remain empty.

To correct this, you can add a third argument to the std::getline function which is a delimitation character that tells the function to stop reading further input after reaching this character(here ',').

Here is an example:

```
std::getline(iss, date, ',');
```

Your modified code should be:

```
void displayGrades(string fileInput, vector<GradeItem> &content) {
  ifstream myFile(fileInput);
  string date, description, type, tempG, tempMG, line;
  int grade, maxGrade;

  std::getline(myFile, line);
  while(std::getline(myFile, line)){
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::getline(iss, date, ',');
    std::getline(iss, description, ',');
    std::getline(iss, type, ',');
    std::getline(iss, tempG, ',');

    grade = stoi(tempG);

    std::getline(iss, tempMG);
    maxGrade = stoi(tempMG);

    GradeItem G(date, description, type, grade, maxGrade);
    content.push_back(G);
  }
}
```